# Custom website font looks odd on Mac devices

Tags: css, fonts, frontend, compatibility, styling

I have added a custom font to my website to fit the theme better, but when using a Mac the font looks weird and is almost inverted. It looks fine on Windows, is there a way I can get it to look right on Mac? If not is there a way to use an entirely different font only on Mac? I'm not an experienced web developer so am not entirely sure how to do this. The website is goldbergphysics.com and the font is [Rob Graves](http://www.fontspace.com/kevin-richey/rob-graves).

Fonts as displayed on MacOS devices
[image: Fonts as displayed on MacOS devices]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll have to use another font for Mac as it seems to render uncorrectly, not only on the web but also within the preview or Font Book, which makes me think it was poorly designed.

Try [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com) instead, there might be some similar font that would suit your needs (and if possible avoid that kind of font providers like Dafont or FontSpace as many of their fonts are not designed for the web).

I would also suggest you to keep it simple by not loading a different font depending on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.platform` in javascript to see if you are on a MAC ( it will return `MacIntel`) and import a different font.

see here [navigator platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform)

For example:

```js
if (navigator.platform === 'MacIntel') {

  let fontLink = document.createElement('link');
  fontLink.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
  fontLink.setAttribute('href', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
  document.head.appendChild(fontLink);


  document.body.style.fontFamily = "Roboto, sans-serif"

}
```